# MS Word - change all tables of specified template to another template

Tags: ms-word, office-automation

I am working on IT project documentation in Word. There are around 500 tables, all of them are as below:

```
_____________________________
|________|________|_________|
|________|________|_________|
|                           |
|___________________________|
```

Now I need to expand all these tables so that there will be 4 cells in each row. Is it possible to do automatically?

Comment: Your diagram seems to suggest that (some of? all of?) the tables have merged cells (the last two lines). Is that correct?

Comment: thanks T.J. Crowder, I appreciate your help. Why project is not a good tag in your opinion? :) bottom cells are merged.

Comment: What would `project` have to do with the question?

Comment: @ Close voters saying the question belongs on superuser: No, it's a question about programming: How do you write Office Automation code to modify the tables?

Comment: I would probably use regexp but first I need to see how tables looks in code. I know it in RTF but not in MS word, can you help me?